# How can I start my prolog web service using a systemctl service on a linux server?

Tags: linux, bash, prolog

I tried to be as explicit as I could in the question but here's my problem...
I'm trying to run a prolog web service on a linux server using systemctl. I created a script that is executed on the server's start, however the web service is being halted automatically after it starts.
Maybe you'll understand better with some code.

I have a prolog file (prolog.pl) and the script file (prolog_init.sh) located at /home/username/

**prolog.pl**

```
:- use_module(library((http/http_open))).
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_client)).
:- use_module(library(http/json)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_json)).

:-dynamic(machine/1).
machine_url("https://my-url.com/api/machine").

:- http_handler('/createMachine', add_Machine, []).

server(Port) :-
        http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

add_Machine(_Request):- /** Some code **/ .
```

**prolog_init.sh**

```
swipl -s /home/username/prolog.pl -g "server(8000)."
```

The service file is located at /etc/systemd/system/

**prolog.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Prolog Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/username/prolog_init.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And these are the commands I execute to set the service up:

```
sudo systemctl start prolog
sudo systemctl enable prolog
```

The problem is that when I check the service's status using `sudo systemctl status prolog` this is the output I get:

```
prolog.service - Prolog Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prolog.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2019-12-27 23:25:41 UTC; 2 days ago
  Process: 112275 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/username/prolog_init.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 112275 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 27 23:25:41 LinuxVM systemd[1]: Started Prolog Service.
Dec 27 23:25:41 LinuxVM bash[112275]: % Started server at http://localhost:8000/
Dec 27 23:25:41 LinuxVM bash[112275]: % halt
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why is my service being halted? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You should post that question at the SWI-Prolog Discourse [forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/). Many of the authors of the code are there and not here.

Comment: Also what version of SWI-Prolog are you using? Note: I can not answer this but I can make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was given to me by a user in an external `PROLOG` forum.

Here's the answer:

> The problem is that the HTTP server runs in a thread and the main thread stops after reading end of file and thus stops the process. One option is to make the toplevel run e.g.,
>
> thread_get_message(Message).
>
> This typically blocks forever, but other threads can make it return by sending a message to the main thread.
>
> Normally I’d advice to use library(http/http_unix_daemon). This provides all the stuff normally associated with managing daemon processes in Unix-like operating systems. Then, the systemd service for e.g. swish is
>
> ```
>     # swi-prolog - SWISH server
>     [Unit]
>       Description=SWISH
>     [Service]
>       UMask=022
>       Environment=LANG=en_US.utf8
>       Restart=on-failure
>       LimitCORE=infinity
>       StartLimitInterval=60
>       StartLimitBurst=5
>       WorkingDirectory=/home/swish/src/swish
>       ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
>       ExecStart=/home/swish/bin/swipl swish-daemon.pl --no-fork --port=80 --user=www-data --workers=4
>     [Install]
>       WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

Don't forget to add `library(http/http_unix_daemon)` in your file.pl

For anyone that has the same or a similar problem, the solution was provided by the user Jan in this [forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group)